# Eliminating noise from ADC readings using digital filters

Tags: capacitor, adc, noise, dsp, snr

I need to take some measurements using MCU internal ADC from the following circuit, to be able to calculate the amount of current produced from the programmable current source which discharging the C2 with time (linear changing in capacitor voltage due to the constant current), MCU1 is responsible for charging C2 via R1 and taking ADC values, maybe the value of R1 needs to be increased but it's not the problem for now.
[image: Figure 1]

But as it seems in the second image 'Oscilloscope Img' three is so much noise on the signal 'Ch3 in purple' so the readings of the ADC are so much noisy and because the values of the capacitor voltage is changed 'Linearly' with every ADC sample the using of simple averaging techniques isn't quite useful.

ADC is taking 20 samples per cycle, where cycle is the discharging time which is controlled by MCU2 and MCU1 is notified with (represented by 'Ch1'), so it maybe 20 samples per sec or 20 samples per 2 ms. These values are used to calculate the \$\Delta V\$ to calculate the amount of current based on it.

There is no access to the circuit components so no analog filters, only the digital filters can be used.
Any suggestions to eliminate these noise?

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: In not following... where exactly are you measuring? Is MCU reading a current from the current source? (If so and you intended a RC filter, then you placed it backwards but you say no analog filters.) Additionally, in order to measure current rather than voltage, you should do so (in the simplest way) across a high precision "shunt" resistor to ground. Furthermore it's pretty pointless to discuss ADC noise without first taking a look at your ADC Vref, because it won't get better than that. Also of course the PCB layout matters a lot. And where you ground the scope probe.

Comment: MCU reading changing in the capacitor voltage, with a constant current the changing is liner, R and C aren't for filtering they are the core of the circuit.
there no way to modify the circuit (the circuit is as is), ADC Vref is the max voltage the chip can handle which in this case (3.3V). and it's not related to the scope side the ADC Sampling values also pickup noise

Comment: So you only measure when the cap is charging up, or...? Because once charged, nothing will (should) happen there. "ADC Vref is the max voltage the chip can handle" Not what I meant - do you supply this from your main dirty 3.3V supply or from a dedicated low noise part? In case of the former, what does the main dirty 3.3V look like (AC trigger on scope)? Could this be switching regulator noise for example?

Comment: Which MCU? Show us a photo of the setup.

Comment: @Lundin, No, I measure the Voltage change while the Discharging operation is being happened due to the Current source, and yes No Low noise part, it's supplied from the same 3.3v.

Comment: @BruceAbbott MCU from StmF4 Series

Comment: Please post a complete schematic - grounds, Supply voltages and clocks. Do you have a separate, filtered Vanalog supply?

Comment: @LiorBilia, it will make no difference as we can't do any thing on the level of electronics the only way is the digital filters, the PCB is not accessible, and no filtered vAnalog supply.

Comment: Please note that all of these noise are on the Capacitor voltage readings. ADC and Analog Vref have nothing to do, as far as i know with the capacitor voltage readings on the oscilloscope.

Comment: Please add your info in comments to your question making it coherent.  Regardless of wheher the circuit (with component values) can be modified or not, a circuit will generate better quality answers than generalities.

Comment: Please show a photo of your measurement setup.

Comment: At first sight, I'd say the ground reference isn't proper, resulting in a lot of spikes coming from the DC rail or other sources in the supply, power circuits, etc. Increasing the 100R would even be worse, adding the sampling capacitance at the input. I think that without good grounding things can't be that better, even with a smaller cap at ADC input...